# Change Firefox location bar search engine

Tags: firefox, search

I have Firefox 3.5, and for some reason Firefox location bar is using Yahoo as the search engine. I couldn't find a setting in the options to change this.

How can I change it back to Google?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer after some searching. Here's how:

- Type **about:config** in the location bar and press Enter
- Type **keyword.URL** in filter
- Change the **keyword.URL** value to:

  http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=

Comment: gr8 tip...some crapware changed my default search too, now I'm back with Google!