# Disable duck search engine in Firefox on Linux mint

Tags: firefox, linux-mint

I *hate* that duck search engine in firefox on Linux Mint. I want to use google search instead when I enter something in the *address bar*.

I'm not talking about the small searchengine bar on the right but the address bar.

Kudos for anyone that can help me change this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the [keyword.URL](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyword.URL) setting of your config (`about:config`).

Compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/22371/144771) for detailed instruction.