# How to use Google autocomplete in the search bar of Firefox?

Tags: firefox, autocomplete

I want use Google autocomplete in the search bar (not search box) of Firefox, like in Google Chrome.

Comment: [I googled "use](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/942545) [google autocomplete in firefox"!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/instantfox/) Isn't it easier then asking a question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Firefox location bar search engine](http://superuser.com/questions/22367/change-firefox-location-bar-search-engine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 1/12/16**

As of Firefox 43, autocomplete for any search engine is available from the location bar.

---

**Outdated**

I've searched for this myself in the past and would also like this feature. As of Firefox 38.0.1, there is no way to do this just as you ask.

Two alternatives (just in case you don't know them already):

1. Using the dedicated search box and enabling the search suggestions
   checkbox in the options menu
2. Using an addon like Omnibar, Instantfox, or Foobar.

Comment: Thanks. I search Omnibar. Just I was going to try when you write the answer.

I don't like InstantFox because I have to write a "g" to search in Google.

Answer (score 0):

Since you like search suggestions, a simple solution is to used [InstantFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/instantfox/).

Comment: I don't like InstantFox because I have to write a "g" to search in Google.